# Generate random numbers and letters

Tags: javascript, php

I need a simple script in PHP/JavaScript to generate 12 random alphanumeric,
contains 8 numbers, and 4 letters.

Such as:

```
923x0w357t9w
74qw0875s3q7
```

Anybody help me to fix this?

Comment: You should try it yourself, then ask when you have a problem or a question.

Comment: Instead of asking you could google it there are literally tons of examples, for exercise it's best to do it yourself which you obviously need.

Comment: I should really like to know why this zero-effort question got an upvote. Voting to close.

Comment: @daan : i all ready google it,but most of them is basic random. i didnt find that checking max number and max letter.

Comment: generate 8 random numbers and 4 random letters, then shuffle them all up

Answer (score 1):

For this you can have an array with all letters and numbers and then use Math.random
We can generate random AlphaNumeric values like this

```
function getAlphaNumeric(){
  var arr =['a','b', 'c', 'd','e','f','g','h','i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n','o','p','q', 'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'],
 letterUsed=0,numberUsed=0,i=0, randomStr='';
 for(;i<12;i++){
  if((Math.floor(Math.random()*2) === 0 && numberUsed <8) || letterUsed>=4){
      randomStr += Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
      numberUsed++;
  }else{    
    randomStr += arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)];
    letterUsed++;
  }
}
return randomStr
}
getAlphaNumeric();
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Solution**

To achieve this first create a random number string with 8 characters. Then create a random string with 4 letters. The final step is to shuffle the concatenated result.

Try this,

```
$randNumber = rand(00000000,99999999); // Numeric string with 8 numbers

$characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
$length = 4;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)]; // 4 letter string
}

$result = str_shuffle($randNumber.$randomString); // Result
echo $result;
```

Comment: i make a few edit in $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'; to $characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

Comment: its work now bro..but if i need more unique millions result, its not work using str.shuffle. any idea my bro ?

Comment: @Def For that you can create the random number string using time stamp. Which is more unique

Comment: honestly i am new for programming, can you give me sample how to use time stamp..

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a neat function for this, here is the code from it:

```
<?php
    function quickRandom($length = 16)
    {
        $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

        return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat($pool, $length)), 0, $length);
    }

    function random($length = 16)
    {
        if (function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes'))
        {
            $bytes = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length * 2);

            if ($bytes === false)
            {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to generate random string.');
            }

            return substr(str_replace(array('/', '+', '='), '', base64_encode($bytes)), 0, $length);
        }

        return quickRandom($length);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a JavaScript version of an easy password generator.

```
function password_generator( len ) {
    var length = (len)?(len):(10);
    var string      = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var stringUpper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    var numeric = '0123456789';
    var punctuation = '!@#$%&*()_+?=';
    var password = "";
    var character = "";
    var crunch = true;
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    while( password.length<length ) {
        entity1 = Math.ceil(string.length * Math.random()*Math.random());
        entity2 = Math.ceil(stringUpper.length * Math.random()*Math.random());
        entity3 = Math.ceil(numeric.length * Math.random()*Math.random());
        entity4 = Math.ceil(punctuation.length * Math.random()*Math.random());
        hold = string.charAt( entity1 );
        character += hold;
        character += numeric.charAt( entity2 );
        character += stringUpper.charAt( entity3 );
        character += (getRandomInt(1, 4) == 1 ? punctuation.charAt( entity4 ) : '');
        password = character;
    }
    return password;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WebJedi/ywd1n12d/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code..

```
function myFunction() {
    var chars = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var nos = "0123456789";
    var string_number = 8;
    var string_char = 4;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_number; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<string_char; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * nos.length);
        randomstring += nos.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    for (var i=0; i<12;i++){
        var a = randomstring.split("");
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = tmp;
    }
        var result = new Array(a.join(""));                  
        console.log(result);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a way to do it in PHP:

```
$alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ0123456789";
    $rand = array(); 
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
        $rand[] = $alphabet[$n];
    }
    echo implode($rand);
```